# How to remove wifi hotspots from list

Tags: tablet, wifi-hotspot

I know the general procedure - hold the wifi network icon and select forget - but the icon still stays there! How can I remove it? (Using Android 6-0-1 on a Samsung Tab)

Comment: Get out of range? It's probably just in range for you to connect.

Comment: Can't get out of range and I cannot turn it off either - I'll just have to put up with it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't get rid of icon, move out of range or switch the hotspot off. Can tell my tab to ignore them and not connect. Went to: https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/make-your-android-automatically-switch-strongest-wifi-network-0172651
Get the Cloudie WiFi Switcher and select the access points you want to use.